# Union of locally finite family of $G_\delta$ sets

Tags: general-topology

Is an arbitrary union of a [locally finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_finite_collection) family of $G_\delta$ sets is again $G_\delta$?

Suppose my collection of $G_\delta$ sets are $\left\{G_\lambda=\bigcap_{i\ge 1} G_i^\lambda:\lambda\in\Lambda\right\}$, where $G_i^\lambda$ are open sets. Then, $$\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda} G_\lambda=\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\bigcap_{i\ge 1}G_i^\lambda=\bigcap_{\alpha\in\mathbb{N}^\Lambda} \bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}G_{\alpha(\lambda)}^\lambda$$ Now, $A_\alpha=\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}G_{\alpha(\lambda)}^\lambda$ is clearly open for each $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^\Lambda$. But I am unable to show that the intersection $\bigcap_{\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^\Lambda}A_\alpha$ can be made countable.

Is my approach correct? Also if the claim is false itself, can someone please provide any counter-example? Any help regarding this is appreciated!

Comment: A space with countable pseudocharacter and having a closed discrete non-$G_\delta$ set would be a counterexample. Mrówka space does not work, I think.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, could you please elaborate? In particular, I am not familiar with the terms pseudocharacter and Mrówka space.

Comment: Mrówka space (or $\Psi$) is a standard example that I described elsewhere. The set of extra points beyond $\omega$ is closed and discrete but it is a $G_\delta$ of course (as its complement $\omega$ is an $F_\sigma$). So that does not work, as I said, but maybe some subset of the extra points would. A space has countable pseudocharacter iff all singleton sets are $G_\delta$. Then writing a closed discrete non-$G_\delta$ subset as the union of its singletons would be a counterexample, hence the remark.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, I checked out the construction of $\Psi$-space. I think any subset of it is itself $G_\delta$ : $A$ be a subset of 'extra points', then $A=\bigcap_{n\ge 1} (A\cup \omega \setminus \{n\})$. So as you noted, it does not serve as a counter-example.

Comment: Indeed. Another would have been the Sorgenfrey plane, but that space is perfect (every closed set is a $G_\delta$). Maybe the Niemytzki plane as well? Then it also wouldn't work as a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a new topology $\tau$ on $\Bbb R$ as follows. Each $x\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ is isolated. For $q\in\Bbb Q$ and $\epsilon>0$ let

$$B(q,\epsilon)=\{q\}\cup\{x\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q:|x-q|<\epsilon\}\;;$$

$\{B(q,\epsilon):\epsilon>0\}$ is local base at $q$. I’ll use $X$ to denote the reals with the topology $\tau$.

Clearly $\Bbb Q$ is a closed, discrete subset of $X$. Moreover, $X$ is first countable, so $\{q\}$ is a $G_\delta$ for each $q\in\Bbb Q$, and $\big\{\{q\}:q\in\Bbb Q\big\}$ is a locally finite family of $G_\delta$ sets.

Suppose that $\Bbb Q\subseteq U\in\tau$; then $U$ contains a Euclidean open nbhd of $\Bbb Q$, which is of course a dense open set in $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology. Let $\{U_n:n\in\Bbb N\}\subseteq\tau$ be a family of open nbhds of $\Bbb Q$ in $X$; without loss of generality we may assume that each $U_n$ is open in the usual topology. By the Baire category theorem $\Bbb Q$ is not a $G_\delta$ in the usual topology of $\Bbb R$, so $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n\ne\Bbb Q$, and $\Bbb Q$ is not a $G_\delta$ in $X$, either.

Comment: I had a hunch that the Michael line would work, but didn't write out the details....

Comment: @Henno: It’s not quite the Michael line, is it? As I recall, in the Michael line the rationals retain their usual nbhds completely, so that $\Bbb Q$ as a subspace still has its usual topology.

Comment: Indeed, it's a bit different. But it's quite similar. But indeed you make the rationals also discrete in itself.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I have one small confusion about this. You said that we can assume any open nbd of $\mathbb{Q}$ to be open in usual topology. What about $U=\mathbb{R}\setminus \{\sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{n} : n\ge 1\}$? I think $U$ is an open nbd of $\mathbb{Q}$ with the new topology, but it's not open in usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, My bad! I get it now. For any nbd $U$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $X$, there is always $V$ open in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{Q}\subset V \subset U$. So, $\mathbb{Q}=\cap U_n = \cap V_n$ contradicts Baire category theorem.

Comment: @ChesterX: Yes, that's exactly right.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott the subsets $\{q\}$ are also functionally closed?

Comment: @user1999: Yes. Let $f:X\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto|x-q|$; every Euclidean open set is open in $X$, so $f$ is continuous, and its zero set is $\{q\}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott that the union of $\{q\}$ i.e $\mathbb{Q}$ is not $G_\delta$ implies that the union i.e $\mathbb{Q}$ is not functionally closed?

Comment: @user1999: Yes, it’s a counterexample of the kind that you want for your current question. (By the way, where in Engelking is that question?)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thank you!. Ryszard Engelking, General topology, pag-49.

Comment: @user1999: You’re welcome, and thank you.