# The union of a locally finite family of functionally closed- RYSZARD ENGELKING

Tags: general-topology

In the book RYSZARD ENGELKING General Topology he states

> Show that the union of a locally finite family of functionally closed sets is not necessarily functionally closed. Note that in a perfectly normal space the union of a locally finite family of functionally closed sets is functionally closed.

A topological space $X$ is called a perfectly normal space if $X$ is a normal space and every closed subset of $X$ is $G_{\delta}$-set.

A subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ is called functionally closed if $A=f^{-1}(0)$ for some continous function $f:X \to [0,1]$

Every closed subset of $X$ is $G_{\delta}$-set means that it countable intersections of open sets

On the other hand,

observation 1: I have proven that a subset $A$ of a normal space is closed $G_{\delta}$ if and only if there exists a continuous function $f:X \to [0,1]$ such that $A=f^{-1}(0)$. i.e, in a normal space functionally closed sets coincide with closed $G_{\delta}$.

A family $\{A_s\}_{s \in S}$ of subsets of a topological space $X$ is locally finite if for every point $x \in X$ there exists a neighbourhood $U$ such that the set $\{s \in S : U \cap A_s \neq \emptyset \}$ is finite.

Any ideas:
Suposse that $X$ is perfectly normal espace.
Let $A=\{A_s\}_{s \in S}$ a locally finite family of functionally closed sets, for observation 1, the $A_s$ are $G_{\delta}$-sets.  We have to find a continuous function $f:X \to [0,1]$ such that $\cup_{s \in S} A_s= f^{-1}(0)$. For each $A_s$ there is a continuous function $f_s: X \to [0,1]$ such that $f_s^{-1}(0)=A_s$.I don't know how to use my hypotheses to build my continuous function f? some help?
On the other hand, I can't think of a counterexample for the first part.

Comment: The name is Ryszard Engelking.

Comment: @PaulFrost Do you have any ideas or a counterexample? please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered, the set $\Bbb Q$ in the space that I constructed in my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1460920/union-of-locally-finite-family-of-g-delta-sets) is the union of a closed, discrete (hence locally finite) family of functionally closed sets but is not itself functionally closed.

For the rest of the question, the union of a locally finite family of closed sets is closed, so if the space is perfectly normal, the union is a $G_\delta$-set and therefore functionally closed.

Comment: In the case in which the locally finite family, let's say $\{A_i\}_i \in I$ is a family of functionally open sets, how could the union be a functionally open set? To prove this
 is to see that $ X \setminus \cup_{i \in I} A_i = \cap_{i \in I} X \setminus A_i $ is a set functionally closed. Could you suggest me an idea to continue the prove, I still don't know where to use the hypothesis that $\{A_i\}_{i \in I}$ is a locally finite family, Thank you.

Comment: @user1999: For each $i\in I$ let $f_i:X\to[0,1]$ have $X\setminus A_i$ as its zero set, and let $f=\sum_{i\in I}f_i$; $f$ is well-defined, since each $x\in X$ is in only finitely many of the sets $A_i$. Clearly the zero set of $f$ is $X\setminus\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$, and you can use the local finiteness of the family to show that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I have serious doubts. Why $ f (x) \in [0,1] $? I know that $ f (x) $ is a finite sum of continuous functions. That's because the family $ \{A_ {i}: i \in I \} $ is locally finite, but I don't know how to justify that sum is not greater than 1. Why not define $ f $ as $ f ( x) = \sum_{i \in I} {2^{- i} f_ {i} (x)}$?

Comment: @Darkmaster: It doesn’t matter whether the sum is greater than $1$. All that matters is that $f$ is continuous and has the right zero set: that ensures that $\bigcup_iA_i$ is functionally open. If for some reason one actually does need the range of $f$ to be contained in $[0,1]$, one can always replace $f$ by $g$, where $g(x)=\min\{f(x),1\}$: $g$ is continuous if $f$ is.

Comment: I have posted an A for the first part, using the Niemitzky plane $N$. Can we characterize the subsets of $\Bbb R \times \{0\}$  that are functionally closed in $N$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $N=\Bbb R\times [0,\infty)$ with the topology of the Niemitzky plane (a.k.a the  Niemitzky-Moore plane). For brevity let $E=\Bbb R\times [0,\infty).$ Then $E$ is a closed discrete subspace of $N$ so every $A\subset E$ is closed in $N.$ We show that every $A\subset E$ is the intersection of a functionally-closed family in $N,$ and that some subsets of $E$ are not functionally-closed in $N.$

For $(r,0)=p\in E$ and $s\in [0,\infty$ let $B(p,s)=\{p\}\cup \{(x,y)\in N:(x-r)^2+(y-s)^2<s^2\}.$ Then $B(p,s)$ is open, and $\overline {B(p,s)}= B(p,s)\cup \{(x,y)\in N:(x-r)^2+(y-s)^2=s^2\}.$

For $p\in E$ and $p\ne q\in B(p,1)$ there is a unique circle $C$ containing $q$ and tangent to $E$ at $p.$ Let $t$ be the radius of $C$  and let $f_p(q)=1-t.$ For $ q\in N$ \ $B(p,1)$ let $f_p(q)=0.$ Let $f_p(p)=1.$ We can confirm that $f_p:N\to [0,1]$ is continuous by observing that if $0<z<1$ then $f_p^{-1}(z,1]=B(p,1-z)$ is open, and $f_p^{-1}[0,z)=N$ \ $\overline {B(p,1-z)}$ is open.

The "point" is that $f_p^{-1}(0,1]$ is functionlly open, and its intersection with $E$ is $\{p\}.$

Now  $N$ \ $E$ is functionally open. So for any $A\subset E,$ the set $F_A=\{N \backslash E\}\cup \{f_p^{-1}(0,1]:p\in E\backslash A\}$ is a functionally open family. If $\cup F_A$ is functionally open then $A=N$ \ $\cup F_A$ is functionally closed.

Let $C(N, \Bbb R)$ be the set of continuous $f:N\to \Bbb R.$ Since $\Bbb R$ is Hausdorff and $N$ is separable, we have $|C(N,\Bbb R)|\le |\Bbb R|^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}.$ But if every $A\subset E$ were functionally closed in $N,$ we would have $|C(N,\Bbb R)|\ge |\{A:A\subset E\}|=2^{2^{\aleph_0}}.$

Comment: The last paragraph is related to the proof of the Jones Lemma.

Comment: The first part of the last paragraph is actually from Corollary 13.14 in the book of Willard